# Parse.com one-to-many issue. Is it possible to fetch everything in one query?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, one-to-many

In my app I'm using `Parse.com` service. And I have entities named `Item` and `Price`. One item may have multiple prices which means that every price object has a reference to its item. Item is not aware of the prices at all. 
And my goal is to fetch an item and its prices in one query. If I had an item having an array of prices it would be very simple. I would do the following:

```
PFQuery* itemsQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Item"];
[itemsQuery includeKey:@"Prices"];
```

but I don't have the array. So I will be forced to have two consecutive queries. First one will fetch the item and once the item is ready I will create the second one:

```
PFQuery* query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Price"];
[query whereKey:@"Item" equalTo:fetchedItem];
```

But I don't like it. I would like to fetch the item and its prices in just one query. Is it even possible to do that without using arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking to much RDBMS and to little NoSQL. The parse database is a NoSQL store, thus you don't have the same characteristics as you would have using a relational database.

The solution in this case is -- which in NoSQL in such cases is more common than joining tables -- to store your prices in an array structure right inside the `Item` entity and query that.

Here is a related link from the `Parse.com` forums:

> https://www.parse.com/questions/how-to-join-several-tables-with-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: but as far as I know it is impossible "to store your prices in an array structure right inside the Item entity", I can only store an array of pointers, not the array of objects, right?

Comment: yes, I think it would work if you'd store an array of pointers and then use something like `query.includeKey("prices")` or something along those lines. Watch out though, you'll probably want to use some Parse SDK to insert those pointers as they have their own kind of structure to do that. From one of my parse backend models, the array looks something like  this: `[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"YourClass","objectId":"qIwoT8wr5g"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"YourClass","objectId":"GGdr5RdhXn"}]`

Comment: the problem (as I said in my question) is I can't have such an array. No way then? just two queries? Or maybe some cloud code function will help?

Comment: I guess not, you'll have to stick with 2 queries. Cloud code won't help you either, the limitation is on the NoSQL store, not the way you access it...

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you cannot make this happen ? It's as easy as adding an array column to your `Item` entity ?

Comment: the server side guy says it is a bad approach to have such an array. he says the many should be aware of the one, not the one of the many

Comment: This is very true for RDBMS systems, not so much for NoSQL. Data integrity and normalization are commonplace in RDBMS, not so much in NoSQL. If you want to optimize query performance, you will have to go with my suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Price' Class will need a 'pointer' column to the item. Pointers are PFObjects, in your case - 'Item' object. Then you can make your query on the 'Price' Class to get an array of price objects back (NSArray *objects):

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Price"];
[query includeKey:@"item"];
[query whereKey:@"item" equalTo:selectedItem]; 
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
   if (objects) {
      // do something with price objects here
   }
}];
```

Comment: you didn't read the question, buddy.  look at this line of yours [query whereKey:@"item" equalTo:selectedItem]; where did you take the item? in the previous query, right? so you have two queries, first for the item and second for the prices. but I need to take it all, item and its prices in just one query

Comment: I have read the docs, but it is not important in this case. look here [query whereKey:@"item" equalTo:selectedItem];. you see? selectedItem. it is already here. Where did you take it? How? When?